# Java - Add two tabs into JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have problem with tabs in the JPanel. I know how to make new tabs in Mainframe, but I don't know how to make tabs into JPanel which is located in Mainframe.

Here are the pictures:

I have program looking like this -
http://www.bildites.lv/viewer.php?file=vklfhvfdfpwpcxllfqv.png

But I want to make it look like this -
http://www.bildites.lv/viewer.php?file=bvbrp4qfx2krn9bkx30j.png

And Here is my code of the blue JPanel:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CallsPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainFrame frame;
    Color color = new Color(99, 184, 255); // steelblue

    public CallsPanel(MainFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;

        this.setLocation(0, 0);
        this.setSize(300, 380);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(color);

        this.initContent();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Declare New Things

    private void initContent() {
        // Add New Things
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Thanks a lot to people that will help!

Comment: You probably need to look at `JTabbedPane`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Tab 1");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Tab 2");

panel1.add(label1);
panel2.add(label2);

tabPane.add("Tab 1", panel1);
tabPane.add("Tab 2", panel2);
this.add(tabPane);
```

Play around with the size/color/shape of the tabPane and see what works for you. But this is the basic of a tabPane.

Comment: Now I see where the problem was.. I had to put also size of the tabPane.. I thought it will be automatically as big as the panel in whom it is into.. Thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score 0):

See this simple runnable example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();

    public MyPanel(){
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        tabPane.add("Panel 1", panel1);
        tabPane.add("Panel 2", panel2);
        tabPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(tabPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MyPanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```